# View Rotation locked

Tags: 3d-view, gizmo

for some reason, blender locks the view rotation. I can pan with middle mouse, but i can't rotate the view. Neither the rotation with the rotation gizmo (new in blender 2.8) in the top right corner works. Clicking on a Axes-Point to rotate to front, left, top, ect. works, but drag and rotate don't. I also tried to lock the view to the camera and rotate via middle mouse or gizmo, but with no success.
This problem happend some days before. Only solution was to load factory defaults. But i don't want to reset every time my settings, only to rotate the view.
Maybe I hit accedently a shortcut that locked the view.

Has someone an idea how to solve this?

thanks
Lukas

file: [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please [share your empty .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), co others can take a look.

Comment: I don't think, its the fault of the file. because when I open an other file, it doesn't work neither. first i thought, the rotate shortcut with the middle mouse button doesn't work anymore. but then i found out, that the rotation with the gizmo didn't work as well.

Comment: Possibly the mouse?

Comment: as I said, pan with the middle mousebutton works fine. and if the mousebutton is broken, why doesn't work draging the gizmo...?